# VBA: Copy paste without clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to do this as one line copy/paste without using the clipboard.
copy one range - row to another sheet paste range - entire row. I need values, not formula.

```
 Sheets("Data").Select 
 ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy

 Sheets("TSP").Select
 ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Do you want to only copy-paste the values? Or also copy-paste the formatted cell(s)?

Comment: Follow the instructions here ==> http://excelexperts.com/copy-values-vba

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This code copy values (not formulas).

```
Sub a()
  Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("TS").Value=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("1:1").Value
End Sub
```

Where "TS" is the name of a range (one row).

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

**Edit**

To copy the active row to Sheet2.Row2 (for example) you may try:

```
Sub a()
 Dim myrow As Integer
 myrow = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Row
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("2:2").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(myrow).Value
End Sub
```

HTH!

Comment: I tried below but failed : Sub a()
  Dim TS As Range
  Set TS = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("2:2") 
  
  Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("TS").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("1:1").Value
End Sub

Comment: 1st will sheet1, range 1:1 find active cell? And, how would set range for activecell, entireRow on sheet2....

Comment: What is the source for your copy? The current row? A specific pre-defined row?

Comment: If the source range contains values starting with the equals-sign `=`, this doesn't work properly, treating those as formulas.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, there isn't. `PasteSpecial` is all about the clipboard.

If you only need values, make a `For` loop copying them.