# "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" Crashes Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have code which opens four workbooks, reformats data, pastes it into the current workbook then closes the other workbooks.

When I close the other workbooks I get a DisplayAlert asking me if I'd like to save the workbook. I want to stop the DisplayAlert appearing.

The recommendation by Microsoft:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

When I do this Excel crashes.

Code:

```
Function rngFoundLog(searchDate As Date)

Set rngSearchLog = Workbooks("Ecom KPI.xlsm").Worksheets("Daily Update Log").Range("A:A")
Set rngFoundLog = rngSearchLog.Find(What:=Sheet1.searchDate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

End Function

Function formatHourlies(fileName As String) As Object

Dim fullFileName As String
fullFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Hourlies\" + fileName
Workbooks.Open fileName:=fullFileName

Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("Top Line Metrics").Range("B9:H32").Copy
Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("Top Line Metrics").Range("A34").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("Top Line Metrics_0").Range("B9:H32").Copy
Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("Top Line Metrics").Range("Y34").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("Top Line Metrics_1").Range("N9:H32").Copy
Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("Top Line Metrics").Range("AW34").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("Top Line Metrics").Range("A34:BT40").Select
Selection.Replace What:="-", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Selection.Copy

End Function

Sub HourlyData()

Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim proxyServer As String
Dim clientID As String
Dim report_period As String
Dim report_date As String
Dim searchDate As Date

Sheet1.proxyServer = Worksheets("Update Data").Range("H2").Value
Sheet1.proxyStatus = Worksheets("Update Data").Range("H1").Value
Sheet1.report_date = Worksheets("Update Data").Range("B2").Value
Sheet1.searchDate = Worksheets("Update Data").Range("B3").Value

Dim answer As Integer
answer = MsgBox("Do you want to import the data?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Import Data?")
If answer = vbYes Then

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String
Dim dateRange As Range
StartTime = Timer

reportDate = Worksheets("Update Data").Range("B3").Value
searchDatev2 = reportDate - 7

Set rngSearch = Worksheets("Business Objects").Range("A:A")
Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=searchDatev2, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

Dim fileName As String
fileName = "couk Hourlies.xlsx"
formatHourlies (fileName)
Workbooks("Ecom KPI.xlsm").Worksheets("Hourlies").Range("B" & rngFound.Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Workbooks(fileName).Close

fileName = "mcouk Hourlies.xlsx"
formatHourlies (fileName)
Workbooks("Ecom KPI.xlsm").Worksheets("Hourlies").Range("EQ" & rngFound.Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Workbooks(fileName).Close

fileName = "ie Hourlies.xlsx"
formatHourlies (fileName)
Workbooks("Ecom KPI.xlsm").Worksheets("Hourlies").Range("KF" & rngFound.Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Workbooks(fileName).Close

fileName = "mie Hourlies.xlsx"
formatHourlies (fileName)
Workbooks("Ecom KPI.xlsm").Worksheets("Hourlies").Range("PU" & rngFound.Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Workbooks(fileName).Close

Workbooks("Ecom KPI.xlsm").Worksheets("Daily Update Log").Range("T" & rngFoundLog(Sheet1.searchDate).Row).Value = Application.UserName

MinutesElapsed = format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

MsgBox "Data Import Completed in " & MinutesElapsed

Else
 'do nothing

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
'Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: In my experience, calling methods such as `Workbooks.Open` inside a `Function` make VBA unstable. Consider instead calling those methods within a `Sub`.

Comment: @xidgel Are you sure? Unless you try to call the Function from a worksheet as an UDF, it is supposed to do everything a Sub does, and more. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @vacip You're correct --- thanks for catching my mistake.

Comment: Opening multiple workbooks means you need to be extra careful with your code. It is much better opening one workbook, copy it, then close it and then paste and format afterwards. Then move on to the next workbook. But anyways I have a similar set up to you, actually a live feed so to speak. an excel files with thousands of cells, data is being pulled from other files using formulas and only relevant information is presented on the feed all formatted and neat. The code I use only ensures that updates go through at x minutes and sorted and conditional formatting takes care of formatting automati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't try to close the active workbook, but set the workbook and close it:

```
Sub closeWorkbook()
Dim workbookToClose As Workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set workbookToClose = Workbooks("WorkbookToClose.xls")
workbookClose.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to save the data try using `ActiveWorkbook.Close False`. This will close the workbook without saving (no prompts) and without using the DisplayAlerts lines. You can also set the active workbook to whatever workbook name you need.

Comment: I was feeling positive about this solution but then it asks me "You have a large amount of data copied to the clipboard".... ah well

Comment: This is because you are using `PasteSpecial` in your code which utilizies the Clipboard. here is a link with tips on how to avoid using the clipboard: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901045/vba-copy-paste-without-clipboard]. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Could you leave the DisplayAlerts in, but for the workbooks you wish to close set the saved flag...

So for example, just before you close Someworkbook:

```
Someworkbook.Saved = true
```

That should stop the message box asking you to save...

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me and I realized that it was happening because I had the VBA editor open. When I closed the VBA editor, and then ran the macro, Excel didn't crash.