# Run-time 1004: Method 'Range' of object 'Worksheet' failed when Paste

Tags: excel, vba

My code will loop through all files in folder and copy information into selected cells from a sheet 'Manager Form' to a masterfile.
When I want to add more ranges to copy, it blocks me with error.

The issue is with this line:
NewSht.Range("B" & PasteRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

How should I specify the range to paste?

```
Dim folderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Masterwb  As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim NewSht As Worksheet
Dim OldSht As Worksheet
Dim FindRng As Range
Dim PasteRow As Long

' set master workbook
Set Masterwb = Workbooks("result2.xlsm")

folderPath = "C:\Users\Downloads\Tech\TimeSheets2019\inside" 'contains folder path

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx*")
Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set NewSht = Masterwb.Worksheets("Tabelle1") ' added
    Set OldSht = wb.Worksheets("Manager Form") ' added

    ' get the first empty row in the new sheet
        Set FindRng = NewSht.Cells.Find(What:="*", Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then ' If find is successful
            PasteRow = FindRng.Row + 1
        Else ' find was unsuccessfull > new empty sheet, should paste at the first row
            PasteRow = 1
        End If

        OldSht.Range("B7").Copy

        NewSht.Range("B" & PasteRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    wb.Close False
```

Comment: What is the value of `PasteRow` when it errors?

Comment: PasteRow should be first empty row, in this case it is 2nd row in NewSht

Comment: If you're just pasting values, why not do `Range(y).Value = Range(x).Value`? It would be significantly faster.

Comment: Are you saying it is 2 or it should be 2?

Comment: My code should copy 5 ranges from each file and copy it one after another in first free row in NewSht. It will contain Name, time, date etc. Currently first empty row is second row, but nothing gets pasted.

Comment: @Tim Stack: you mean to writ it like that? NewSht.Range("B" & PasteRow).Value = OldSht.Range("B7").Value Unfortunately that is not main cause of the error. I think I need to specify somewhere PasteRow location

Comment: @Eve right, as with [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901045/vba-copy-paste-without-clipboard).

Comment: but then I cannot paste special, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
' get the first empty row in the new sheet
 Dim target as range
 Set target = newsht.cells(NewSht.usedrange.rows.count +1,2)
```

OR

```
 Dim target as Range
 Set target = newsht.cells(newsht.rows.count,2).end(xlup).offset(1,0)
```

Then

```
  target.formula = OldSht.Range("B7").value  'copy value into blank cell
```

Comment: Second solution works. Thanks a lot. But when I try to replace "B7" with some range like "B7:B15" it still copy only B7. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Do you want to copy into target to target +8 cells down?

Comment: I solved this one but with Copy so it is slower: OldSht.Range("B7:B15, B17:B26").Copy  NewSht.Cells(NewSht.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues. But after filling column B, I would also like to fill column A, with Person Name, until the last row. And I got stuck with that